# basic code for copy transpose paste to next row

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste, transpose

I'm completing a tracker. user will complete questions one one sheet - each answer will be in a cells (B2-B8) and copied to a row in another sheet. I want to paste to the next available line.

I have tried code that copies the range (B2-B8) and then paste transpose=True. This was an error. The next I tried coping each cell and pasting each cell. But not sure how to add in the paste to next row.  I can't remember the coding to use to create a loop with set range or the code to add to next available row.

```
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Settlement Request").Select
Range("B3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("B5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Settlement Request").Select
Range("B4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("C5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I have not gotten that far. When I tried the transpose = true I got a compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach might be:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransferAnswersToSomeSheet()

    ' Copying a vertical range (on "Settlement Request" sheet)
    ' and pasting to a horizontal range (on "Sheet2" sheet).

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Settlement Request") ' If there is a workbook, specify it too e.g. ThisWorkbook or Workbooks("someWorkbookName")

    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Set destinationSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2") ' If there is a workbook, specify it too e.g. ThisWorkbook or Workbooks("someWorkbookName")

    Dim cellToPasteTo As Range
    Set cellToPasteTo = destinationSheet.Cells(destinationSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    sourceSheet.Range("B2:B8").Copy
    cellToPasteTo.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Transpose:=True

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

- The code above will paste as values (whilst preserving original number formatting). If this is not appropriate for you, you can replace `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` in the code with the options shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype.
- The logic (in the code) is to find the last value in column A and paste to the row immediately below. The last value is found using `Range.End(xlUp)` and we access the cell immediately below it using `Range.Offset(1,0)`.